# Rake command not found after messing with PATH -- Also, no rails commands work either

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, classpath, rhomobile

Changing my system PATH variable seems to have just screwed up everything.

So, I was trying to run `rake device:android:production` to make an APK of the app I've been working on with RhoMobile / Rhodes. I got an error telling me that something with my `java bin` folder was off, so I went and examined my system PATH variable and changed it to my JDK bin folder. It was previously some path that RhoMobile added when I installed it.

So, now I'm getting `Rake Command Not Found` instead of the `java bin folder not found` error I was getting before.

I can't run `rails server` or any `rails` or `gem` commands either, and for some reason even commands like `ls` aren't working for me any more.

How the heck can I get this working again and what did I do?

Changing my PATH allowed me to finally use `javac` and `java` commands, but screwed up literally everything else. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question?  It sounds like you may have removed too much from it.  `PATH` contains multiple entries, separated by `:`.  It's a list of directories to be searched in sequential order.  If you set it to just one directory, then you're not going to be able to run any commands except those in that directory.  If you're using `RVM`, it does a bunch of magic behind the scenes to manage your `PATH`.  You can do `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to have it re-set your `PATH`.  Normally you put that line in your shell startup file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` or similar).

Comment: @JimStewart The problem is that I deleted my whole path variable on accident (which held the ruby path and other paths) and replaced it with only my JDK path. I ran an installation of the RhoMobile suite and that installed rails and ruby and set my path automatically. echo $PATH just returns "$PATH". Also, when I use certain IDE's, things still work, but anything I try to do via command line does not work anymore.

Comment: If you just changed it by setting `PATH` from the command-line, then close the shell/window/session and/or log out, and it'll be back the way it was when you log back in.  `PATH` changes only persist if you've modified your environment permanently by editing your shell config.  You can also try setting it back to a reasonable value, but you don't mention what OS you're using, and defaults vary.  Something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` is a good starting point on a Unix system; that'll get you the core system functionality.

Comment: @JimStewart I changed it by going to Computer>Advanced Settings>Environment Variables and editing the entry in PATH (Windows 7). I tried adding the `/ruby/bin` path to it to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, Windows Ruby installs aren't my forte, and they aren't consistent.  You might want to add specifics about your OS and your Ruby package to the question.  This is getting verbose so I'm going to bow out before the comments overflow.

Comment: @JimStewart No problem, I was hoping for some magic solution, but I may just uninstall and reinstall everything if no one comes along. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem like a Ruby question, but if you're on Windows I assume you're running either the Windows Installer version([rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org)) or JRuby?

The PATH variable should contain

```
c:\ruby200-x64\bin
```

or

```
c:\jruby-1.7.3\bin
```

or the respective path to your local ruby.

Comment: Well, it started out as a ruby question, because I screwed my paths up while working with ruby. What happened was, I accidentally deleted my system PATH variable and it screwed up tons of stuff (ruby included). So basically, I have to figure out all the compilers and things I use and re-add them to my PATH. I was kind of looking for an easy way to restore it, but as of now, I'm just reinstalling everything -_-

Comment: No! Don't! Just change your path. Maybe we should switch to another Stackexchange site if you don't know how to do that?

Comment: I do know I can just change my path, but I don't know what the PATH is supposed to be, because all of those installers added different paths to it. It's not just ruby's path that's missing.

Comment: If you have System Protection enabled (that would be default) you might be able to revert to the previous restore point.

Comment: I was going to do that, but unfortunately,I don't have a restore point :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26903/discussion-between-steffen-roller-and-scotch)